# jQuery val() on HTML Select Text takes precedence over Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Take the below HTML select for an example:**

```
<select name="selValues" id="selValues">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">5</option>
    <option value="4">3</option>
</select>
```

If we write the following jQuery statement:

```
$('#selValues').val('2'); // Two will get selected
$('#selValues').val('3'); // 3 will get selected instead of 5??
```

Why is it like that?

Comment: Post this as a bug over at jquery.com

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature, as I explained in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$("#selValues option[value='3']").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Also a good article on

[jQuery - Select elements - tips and tricks](http://myphpetc.blogspot.com/2009/03/jquery-select-elements-tips-and-tricks.html)

Comment: Yes that statement would work, I know that. But if the value you are trying to select is not present in the list, then the selected value should change to -1 (no items selected). But it doesn't happen with this statement.

Answer (score 2):

The val() method gets or sets the selected text. You may want to use selectedIndex instead:

```
$('#selValues').get(0).selectedIndex=2;
```

Answer (score 2):

When selecting options jQuery looks first at the value then at the text of an option. It also goes through options in order. So, `$('#selValues').val('3')` selects options 3 first, but right after that changes selection to option 4 (as it has the text "3"). Use a multiple select to see that in fact both options are selected

```
<select name="selValues" id="selValues" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">5</option>
    <option value="4">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You are right .. but it doesn't solve my issue .. If I specify the value in the selector it will work.

'#selValues option[value="3"]'


But if the value that I am trying to select is not present in the list, then no item should be selected. This doesn't happen with jQuery but happens with normal JavaScript if I just write:

$('#selValues')[0].value = <Value Here>;

Answer (score 2):

As of JQuery 1.4 this has now been made unambiguous. It will now select by value, not by text value http://jquery14.com/day-01#backwards

If you do need to still select by value then a suggested method is [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/select-dropdown-by-text)